# Jquery ajax data is returned but success function is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Module/findByType',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            request: 'ajax',
            type_id: id
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            var i = 0;
        })
```

this generates the following output:

```
[{"id":"267","Category_id":"1","name":"Adf\u00e6rdsscreening","description":"Denne adf\u00e6rdsscreening tager udgangspunkt i Adam Adf\u00e6rds 5 parametre, og du giver karakter ud\nfra en skala fra 1 til 4, hvor 4 er bedst.","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"10","is_private":"1","module_type":"9","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Screening","type_color":"bg-Survey","category_name":"Adf\u00e6rd","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/adfard.png","color":"bg-adfard","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"271","Category_id":"4","name":"Samtalescreening","description":"Jo mere du \u00f8ver dig p\u00e5 noget, jo dygtigere bliver du til det. M\u00e5ske har du\r\nf\u00f8r oplevet, at du g\u00f8r store fremskridt i de f\u00f8rste uger, derefter g\u00e5r det\r\nlangsommere og langsommere.\r\nOg til sidst g\u00e5r det helt i st\u00e5, m\u00e5ske endda i lange perioder.","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"10","is_private":"1","module_type":"9","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Screening","type_color":"bg-Survey","category_name":"Kommunikation","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/kommunication.png","color":"bg-Kommunikation ","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"289","Category_id":"1","name":"Test screening","description":"","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"10","is_private":"1","module_type":"9","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Screening","type_color":"bg-Survey","category_name":"Adf\u00e6rd","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/adfard.png","color":"bg-adfard","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"292","Category_id":"1","name":"Test 2","description":"","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"0","is_private":"1","module_type":"9","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Screening","type_color":"bg-Survey","category_name":"Adf\u00e6rd","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/adfard.png","color":"bg-adfard","is_owned":"true"}]
```

Which i can see from the developer tool in chrome.

However the success function is never called.

Can someone see what the problem might be?

**Update**

Okay here is the thing:

I have two sides of the ajax call depending on the type_id so here is my very complicated PHP code:

```
        public function findByType()
    {

        if ($_SESSION['User']['type'] <= 2) {
            if(isset($_POST['type_id']))
            {
                $organization_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('
          SELECT Module.*, MT.name as type_name, MT.color as type_color, C.name as category_name, C.image_path as image_path, C.color FROM module Module
           INNER JOIN organization_has_module OHOM
           ON Module.id = OHOM.Module_id JOIN category C ON C.id = Module.category_id INNER JOIN module_type MT on MT.id = Module.module_type
           WHERE OHOM.Organization_id = ' . $_SESSION['User']['org'] . '
           AND Module.module_type = ' . $_POST['type_id'].' AND Module.status_id != 0', MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
                $all_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('SELECT
    M . *,
    MT.color as type_color,
    MT.name as type_name,
    C.name as category_name,
    C.image_path as image_path,
    C.color
FROM
    module M
        JOIN
    category C ON C.id = M.category_id
        JOIN
    module_type MT ON MT.id = M.module_type
WHERE
    M.module_type = '.$_POST['type_id'].' AND is_private = 0 AND M.status_id != 0', MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
            }
            else
            {
                $organization_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('
          SELECT Module.*, MT.name as type_name, MT.color as type_color, C.name as category_name, C.image_path as image_path, C.color FROM module Module
           INNER JOIN organization_has_module OHOM
           ON Module.id = OHOM.Module_id JOIN category C ON C.id = Module.category_id INNER JOIN module_type MT on MT.id = Module.module_type
           WHERE OHOM.Organization_id = ' . $_SESSION['User']['org'] . '
           AND Module.module_type = ' . $_POST['type_id'].' AND Module.status_id != 0', MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
                $all_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('SELECT
    M . *,
    MT.color as type_color,
    MT.name as type_name,
    C.name as category_name,
    C.image_path as image_path,
    C.color
FROM
    module M
        JOIN
    category C ON C.id = M.category_id
        JOIN
    module_type MT ON MT.id = M.module_type
WHERE
    M.module_type = '.$_POST['type_id'].' AND is_private = 0 AND M.status_id != 0', MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);

            }
            if($organization_modules)
            {
                if($all_modules == null)
                {
                    $all_modules = array();
                }
                foreach ($organization_modules as $module)
                {
                    $is_owned = false;
                    $module['is_owned'] = 'true';

                    $module['name'] = $module['name'];
                    for ($i = 0, $size = count($all_modules); $i < $size; $i++)
                    {
                        $all_modules[$i]['name'] = $all_modules[$i]['name'];
                        if($all_modules[$i]['id'] == $module['id'])
                        {
                            $is_owned = true;
                            $all_modules[$i]['is_owned'] = 'true';
                        }

                    }
                    if(!$is_owned)
                    {
                        array_push($all_modules, $module);
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($_POST['type_id']))
                {

                    $all_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('SELECT M.*, C.name as category_name, C.image_path as image_path, C.color FROM module M JOIN category C ON C.id = M.category_id JOIN module_type MT ON MT.id = M.module_type WHERE M.module_type = ' . $_POST['type_id'].' AND is_private = 0', MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
                }
                else
                {

                    $all_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('SELECT M.*, C.name as category_name, C.image_path as image_path, C.color FROM module M JOIN category C ON C.id = M.category_id JOIN module_type MT ON MT.id = M.module_type WHERE M.module_type = ' . $_POST['type_id'].' AND is_private = 0', MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
                }

            }
        } else {
            $all_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('
            SELECT M.*, C.name as category_name, C.image_path as image_path, C.color, MT.name as type_name, MT.color as type_color FROM module M
            INNER JOIN user_has_module UHOM
            ON M.id = UHOM.Module_id
              JOIN
            category C ON C.id = M.category_id INNER JOIN module_type MT ON M.module_type = MT.id
            WHERE UHOM.user_id = ' . $_SESSION['User']['id'] . ' AND M.category_id = ' . $_POST['category_id'], MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);

            for ($i = 0, $size = count($all_modules); $i < $size; $i++)
            {
                $all_modules[$i]['is_owned'] = 'true';
            }
        }

        print json_encode($all_modules);
    }
```

When i call this with id 9 then i get the above json and the success function is not called.

When i call this function with id 4 then i get the following json:

```
[{"id":"217","Category_id":"2","name":"Online session 1","description":"Guitar online session 1, du l\u00e6rer her de basale ting omkring en guitar","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"5","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Forretningsforst\u00e5else","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/forretningsfortaelse.png","color":"bg-business","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"222","Category_id":"10","name":"Online session 2","description":"Guitar online session 2. Du er nu klar til at blive testet.","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"20","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Psykologi","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/psykologi.png","color":"bg-phys","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"231","Category_id":"1","name":"Basisviden 1","description":"Basisviden Test 1 beskrivelse","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"15","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Adf\u00e6rd","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/adfard.png","color":"bg-adfard","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"262","Category_id":"7","name":"Ledelsesstile","description":"Med udgangspunkt i Kurt Lewins tre overordnede ledelsesformer, s\u00e5 skal du nu tage stilling til f\u00f8lgende\nudsagn og v\u00e6lge hvilken ledelsesform som passer til udsagnet.","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"10","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Ledelse","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/ledelse.png","color":"bg-Ledelse ","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"263","Category_id":"4","name":"Kender du typen (DISC)","description":"Vi har nu gennemg\u00e5et disc-terminologien og de forskellige adf\u00e6rdstyper,\ns\u00e5 alle er blevet pr\u00e6senteret for adf\u00e6rden bag de fire typer. Derfor er der\nher en lille stikpr\u00f8ve.","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"10","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Kommunikation","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/kommunication.png","color":"bg-Kommunikation ","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"264","Category_id":"4","name":"Min profil (DISC)","description":"\u00c9n ting er at kunne identificere menneskers adf\u00e6rdsprofil - men kender du din egen?","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"10","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Kommunikation","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/kommunication.png","color":"bg-Kommunikation ","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"281","Category_id":"11","name":"Sp\u00f8rgeteknik","description":"What, why, how er en sp\u00f8rgeteknik. \n\nAt stille et sp\u00f8rgsm\u00e5l er ikke et m\u00e5l i sig selv, kun et middel til at n\u00e5 m\u00e5let.","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"10","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Salg & Performance","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/salgogperformance.png","color":"bg-salg ","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"287","Category_id":"3","name":"Pol - test","description":"Dette er en test om Politiken","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"5","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Internt","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/internt.png","color":"bg-Internt","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"290","Category_id":"3","name":"Entercard Test","description":"Test din viden om Entercard","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"5","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Internt","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/internt.png","color":"bg-Internt","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"298","Category_id":"9","name":"Boconcept intro","description":"Dette er en beskrivelse","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"10","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Produkter","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/produkter.png","color":"bg-Produkter","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"302","Category_id":"6","name":"Test Sitel","description":"Tester test ","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"10","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Kultur","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/kultur.png","color":"bg-Kultur","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"304","Category_id":"1","name":"tester video","description":"1234","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"0","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Adf\u00e6rd","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/adfard.png","color":"bg-adfard","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"305","Category_id":"1","name":"Testing video 2","description":"1234","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"0","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Adf\u00e6rd","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/adfard.png","color":"bg-adfard","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"306","Category_id":"1","name":"Video vs lyd","description":"1234","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"0","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Adf\u00e6rd","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/adfard.png","color":"bg-adfard","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"310","Category_id":"1","name":"\u00f8\u00e5\u00e6","description":"213","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"0","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Adf\u00e6rd","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/adfard.png","color":"bg-adfard","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"312","Category_id":"9","name":"Produkt gennemgang","description":"","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"0","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Produkter","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/produkter.png","color":"bg-Produkter","is_owned":"true"},{"id":"313","Category_id":"9","name":"Produkt gennemgang","description":"","price":"0","mentor":null,"location":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"is_online":"1","status_id":"1","Material_id":null,"duration":"0","is_private":"1","module_type":"4","gives_score":"1","type_name":"Test","type_color":"bg-type_default","category_name":"Produkter","image_path":"\/site\/resources\/images\/category_icon\/produkter.png","color":"bg-Produkter","is_owned":"true"}]
```

and success function is displayed

Comment: How do you say that the success function is never called? As the success function doesn't do anything interactive, you cannot just say this.

Comment: i think the problem is in your PHP code and not the JS.
can you upload it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar ive tried to alert in the success fucntion

Comment: Your serverside code may not be returning data in correct format, but data you see, might seem ok.

Comment: @ArindamNayak i can post my php code

Comment: you are echoing json_encode($data)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Yes, you can @MarcRasmussen, just add an `error` function which takes 3 param, capture error there. As suggested above use `echo json_encode($all_modules);` instead of `print`

Comment: @ArindamNayak The error function is not called either

Comment: @MarcRasmussen, I think you are missing an curly brace `}` after success function bracket close, make sure you don't have any JS quirks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use async : false on your ajax code, by default async is true, here is the example of it

$.ajax({

```
type: 'POST',
url: '/Module/findByType',
dataType: 'json',
async : false,
data: {
    request: 'ajax',
    type_id: id
},
success: function (data)
{
    var i = 0;
    console.log("Value of i:" + i);
    console.log("Result:" + data);
})
```

Comment: Same result nothing is called

Comment: I guess the issue is in PHP not in JS. Your Js code looks good. Please check PHP code

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you would be using the value of `i` after the `success` function. But since the request is asynchronous and you read the value of `i` synchronously, you might not be able to get the final value, as the JavaScript executes the command before the AJAX Call.

May be you can do this. Instead of `alert()`, you can use `console.log()` and check if the function is getting executed. This is the right way.

My suggestion would be to put the code that uses the value of `i` after the AJAX call inside a function and call the function in the `success` function of the AJAX call.

Comment: He said he tried to alert in the success block and it never happened.

Comment: @IdanMagled Updated the answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no issue with the code, you just alert / console.log  the data inside the success, please see the sample below,

```
$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Module/findByType',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        request: 'ajax',
        type_id: id
    },
    success: function (data)
    {
        var i = 0;
        console.log("Value of i:" + i);
        console.log("Result:" + data);
    })
```

Comment: The success function is never called. so none of the code is executed